# Do not search in comments Visual C++ 2010

Tags: search, regex, visual-studio-2010

Somewhere in the code, I've forgotten `std::cout<<` which is now messing up my console. But my code us full of commented debug outputs and VC++ searches through all of them, making it impossible to find my problem.
I think it could be solved with the regular expression option in search dialog. Have you any idea, what pattern should I use to avoid searching `cout` in `//comment` and `/*comment*/`?

Summary:
**How to ignore comments while searching text in Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153876/how-can-i-search-in-visual-studio-and-get-it-to-ignore-what-is-commented-out

Answer (score 1):

`^[^/*]*std::cout<<` should find any occurrence of `std::cout<<` that doesn’t have any slashes or asterisks to its left.  Notes: (1) If you’re using `/` to initiate your search, you will probably need to put a backslash before the slash in the regex.  (2) This will not find code to the right of a `*/`.  (3) If you write multiple statements on a line, this regex will be messed up by anything in a statement to the left of the one you’re looking for.

Comment: Ad (3): Not only that, this code also will not work for `//` and I'm afraid it will require no spaces between comment and command. But this cold maybe fixed using `[ ]*`.

Comment: @TomášZato: I don’t understand you.  I just tested it (in `vi`) and it worked correctly for `//`, and I really have no idea what you mean by “it will require no spaces between comment and command.”  I already said that my regex will not find code to the right of a `*/`.  Please explain.